# Careers listings don't onebox in chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, chat

Careers.SE posts used to onebox in Server Fault chat. They don't anymore. This makes us sad when we want to make fun of some of the sillier job postings.

[image: Screenshot of chat]

Examples:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12482999#12482999

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12483054#12483054

Comment: NEED MOAR FREEHAND CIRCLES. There. Got that out of the way.

Comment: *please* include a link in your bug reports, screenshots are good but way less useful unless it's an actual graphical glitch.

Comment: @NickCraver Added a couple of examples. It doesn't look like it's working anywhere, so I didn't bother linking to specific examples in the original report.

Comment: Matt Sherman on the Careers team is rolling out a fix now, just an unintentional casualty on a big changeset a few days ago.

Comment: @NickCraver [Obligatory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6PZhONZ3Ac). Please pass it along to the Careers team. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I broke it and fixed it, a ploy to ensure job security. Thanks for the heads-up, try it again?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Excellent - the website no longer tastes purple!